# Server won't respond to requests from a different subnet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

This looks to me like a poor question, but I'm stumped.

I have a Win2k8 R2 server that I had to move.  It now resides on our 192.168.1.0 subnet,  Everything seems to be fine within that subnet.  It's Roles are DC, DNS, and Remote Desktop. All services are working for any client on the .1.0 network, but no requests get a response if they come from any other network (the other 192.168.2.0 subnet or the internet.)  Forwarding and firewall on the gateway are verified (all other hosts respond and all connections get through).  Firewall on the server can be enabled or not.

I feel I'm missing a configuration on the server I didn't think of...  Does moving the server freak out AD DS?  I didn't change the computer name or location info, just the IP address.  Why won't it respond to other networks?

Comment: So you can't ping 192.168.1.<DC> from 192.168.2.0/24? But you can ping every other host?

Comment: have you tried telnet?

Comment: I tried everything (telnet is not installed)...  After banging my head against it for hours, I found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to walk away for five minutes, have a cup of coffee, and realize that your AV software is blocking it.

Kaspersky's enterprise version (new to me) blocks ping and RDS ports by default, along with a host of others.  The odd thing is that it doesn't block them from the same subnet, a function of the trusted locations heirarchy.  Opening up the ports in Kaspersky solved the problem.